# Using send with OpenStruct

Tags: ruby

I wrote a class like so:

```
class Query < OpenStruct
  def initialize(search)
    assign_attributes search
  end

  def assign_attributes(search)
    search.each do |k,v|
      puts "k #{k} v #{v}"
      send("#{k}=",v)
    end
  end
end
```

I expected to be able to do the following:

```
e = Query.new( {a: "a", b: "b", c: "c"} )
e.a # => a
e.b # => b
e.c # => c
```

Instead this is what happens:

```
e = Query.new( {a: "a", b: "b", c: "c"} )
k a v a
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass
```

Usually send works fine with dynamic assignment like this. Is there a conflict with OpenStruct? What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Try to call `super()` before calling `assign_attributes`

Comment: @Stefan that is exactly what the problem was.

Comment: It might have helpful to have commented out `assign_attributes search`, then `e = Query.new( {a: "a", b: "b", c: "c"} ); e.instance_variables #=> []; Query.instance_methods(false) #=> [:assign_attributes]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With warnings turned on, I get this one in addition to your error:

```
/.../ruby/2.1.0/ostruct.rb:157: warning: instance variable @table not initialized
```

It seems that OpenStruct needs to do some initialization on its own.

Calling `super()` resolves the problem:

```
class Query < OpenStruct
  def initialize(search)
    super()
    assign_attributes search
  end

  # ...
end
```